# Yii How to add link into opentag table text

Tags: php, yii

How to add link into opentag table text ?

**In Yii Code like this:**

echo CHtml::tag('td', array('class'=>"apptd2"), CHTML::encode($model->gametitle));

**In source code like this:**

```
<td class="apptd2">
     Gametitle
</td>
```

**What I want is:**

```
<td class="apptd2">
     <a href="#">Gametitle</a>
</td>
```

**How to add a href for yii opentag code ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use `CHtml::link()` as second parameter of `CHtml::tag`. Example:

```
echo CHtml::tag(
    'td',
    array('class'=>"apptd2"),
    CHtml::link(
        CHtml::encode($model->gametitle),
        '#'
    )
 );
```